# Regex for multiple emails separated by commas with valid emails

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex to check multiple valid emails separated by commas, But I'm not able to update it to allow multiple trailing and leading whitespace. I should allow below pattern to match my regex.

```
abc@test.com,bcd@test.com, new@test.com,   hello@test.com   ,new@test.com // allow
abc@test.com bcd@test.comnew@test.com// don't allow
```

Regex which I've now.

```
^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$
```

The above regex is not allowing the pattern

```
abc@test.com,bcd@test.com, new@test.com,   hello@test.com   ,new@test.com
```

It allows only one white space before an after the comma. I want the regex to allow multiple white space before and after the comma

Comment: `\s?` means "0 or 1 whitespace character" (or "an optional whitespace character"). Change them into `\s*` "0 or more whitespace characters". I suggest taking a quick regex tutorial, quantifiers are the basics and you'll probably be much more confortable with regexs in the span of 15-30 minutes.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm

Comment: Other suggested changes : add `@` to the negated classes that are just before `@`, `.` to the negated classes that are just before `\.` and add an extra `\s*` at the end before the `$` anchor (your current regex wouldn't match lists of email with trailing whitespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Why not first spiting the string:

```
function getValidEmailAddresses(strInput)
{
return strInput.split(',').map(p => p.trim())
               .filter(c=> c.test(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/));

}
```